# React Native - iOS CustomUserAgent from Native Modules for Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

So I have a reactnative project in which when platfrom is iOS some lines of code are being executed:

```
import { NativeModules, Platform } from "react-native";
if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    const { CustomUserAgent } = NativeModules;
    CustomUserAgent.registerCustomUserAgent('a new user agent');
}
```

And I want to have something similar for Android devices. Since I am not a reactnative developer, I thought that all I have to do is to dupplicate this and replace `iOS` with 'android' and it should work but I got this error `Cannot read property 'registerCustomUserAgent' of null`.

So I guess that the NativeModules contain something different depending on the platform but looking here https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios and here https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android I did not find anything.

How can I build a flow like this for Android devices ?